# Is this a good way for knowing if the code has changed after submission to a customer?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm looking for a way to see if any files have changed once I submit code to a customer. Usually, I'd check the hash on a git commit or gpg sign a .zip file. I'm looking for a way to do this "in place" without git or zip.

I'd calculate the md5 hash of all the files in the directories given by `find ... -ls` and if any has changed in datetime or size, the md5 checksum should be different.

```
find . -type d \( -path ./data -o -path ./dbms-data -o -path ./log \) -prune -o -type f ! -name "*.json" ! -name "*.txt" -ls | md5sum
```

Would this work? And am I correctly omitting the files and directories?

Comment: Have you tried your command?